# Remove the rows that have non-numeric characters in one column in R

Tags: r

In the data frame, column A is expected to be  a numeric vector.

So if an entry of the column has any non-numeric characters, I would remove the corresponding entire row.

Does anyone have a solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When you import data to a data.frame, it generally gets converted to a factor if the entire column is not numeric. With that in mind, you usually have to convert to character and then to numeric.

```
dat <- data.frame(A=c(letters[1:5],1:5))

str(dat)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ A: Factor w/ 10 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 6 7 8 9 10 1 2 3 4 5

as.numeric(as.character(dat$A))
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA  1  2  3  4  5
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

Notice that it converts characters to `NA`. Combining this:

```
dat <- dat[!is.na(as.numeric(as.character(dat$A))),]
```

In words, the rows of `dat` that are not `NA` after conversion from factor to numeric.

Second Issue:

```
> dat <- data.frame(A=c(letters[1:5],1:5))
> dat <- dat[!is.na(as.numeric(as.character(dat$A))),]
Warning message:
In `[.data.frame`(dat, !is.na(as.numeric(as.character(dat$A))),  :
  NAs introduced by coercion
> dat <- dat[!is.na(as.numeric(as.character(dat$A))),]
Error in dat$A : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Comment: Thank you. I applied your input to my own dataset and it got through.  However, when I used your example here and typed in: dat[!is.na(as.numeric(as.character(dat$A))),]
I got: Error in dat$A : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors.  Sorry I'm new to R and would appreciate your further advice. Thanks!

Comment: There was a missing `)`. But I supsect you overwrote `dat` once, and then tried to run the same command on it again.

Answer (score 3):

Or using @Brandon Bertelsen's example data

```
dat1 <- transform(dat[grep("^\\d+$", dat$A),,drop=F], A= as.numeric(as.character(A)))
dat1
#   A
#6  1
#7  2
#8  3
#9  4
#10 5

 str(dat1)
#'data.frame':  5 obs. of  1 variable:
#$ A: num  1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: This doesn't produce a warning like @Brandon Bertelsen's answer, Thank you

Comment: A more thorough regexp if you are looking for floats or numbers with exponents:  `"^[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$"`

Comment: Answering a slightly different question, where I wanted to segregate the "numbers" and the "strings", I did it like so: `foo <-split(dat, ifelse(regexpr("^[-+]?\\d*\\.?\\d+([eE][-+]?\\d+)?$", dat$A)==1, "numbers", "strings"))`.  I liked this because it only had to do the regex search once.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to create a data frame from non-numerical values.

```
subset(df, grepl('^\\d+$', df$dfColumn))
```

You can add an exclamation sign to the code to take a look at non-numerical values and make sure you want to delete them. If a column value is detected as non-numerical due to existence of a space in it, e.g '143  ', it is worth deleting the space instead of deleting the value from your column.

```
    subset(df, !grepl('^\\d+$', df$dfColumn))
```