# How to delete a row in R that doesn't have a number

Tags: r, dataframe

My data looks like:

```
SNP             A1      A2      EFF                     FRQ
rs12565286      C       G       -0.00225985777786465    .04354
rs11804171      A       T       -0.00530020318295282    .04485
rs3094315       A       G       -0.0042551489236695     .8364
rs12562034      A       G       -0.00911972489527125    .09763
rs12124819      A       G       0.0250148724382224      .
rs2980319       A       T       0.0178927256033542      .1306
rs4040617       A       G       -0.0173263263037023     rabbit
```

I would like to delete the rows that contain "." and that contain "rabbit". Is there a way to keep the numbers? The reason I want to do this is because I'm using a large data file for a manipulation and I am getting a `1 - gwas.data$FRQ[i] : non-numeric argument to binary operator` error. Am I right in assuming the error is because some data isn't a number? I haven't even checked to see if the data has non-numeric values in the column because it's 3 million lines long.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25276155/remove-the-rows-that-have-non-numeric-characters-in-one-column-in-r

Comment: So you would expect the 5th and 7th rows to be deleted?

Comment: If the row is of a `character` type (try inspect it by using `class(your_data_table['FRQ'])`), then maybe you can use `lapply` on it combined with a use of `grep`.

Comment: Assuming this is a data.frame and not a matrix, have you tried coercing that column to numeric with `as.numeric`?

Comment: After wards, you can create a vector of row numbers that you'd like to keep and filter perhaps by `your_data_table[rows_kept %in% total_rows]` where `rows_kept` and `total_rows` are some sort of key for the rownames or row indices.

Comment: please provide `dput` output of your data frame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example data.frame:

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=1:10, FRQ=c(rnorm(8), '.', 'rabbit'), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

To check the class of all your columns try: `lapply(df, class)`

If the FRQ column is character, you can convert it to numeric by removing all non-numerics, then convert to numeric. Like this:

```
library(stringr)
df <- df[!str_detect(df$FRQ, '([A-Za-z])'), ]
df <- df[!str_detect(df$FRQ, '\\.$'), ]
df$FRQ <- as.numeric(df$FRQ)
```