# Convert non-numeric rows and columns to zero

Tags: r

I have this data from an r package, where X is the dataset with all the data

```
library(ISLR)
data("Hitters")
X=Hitters
head(X)
```

here is one part of the data:

```
                 AtBat Hits HmRun Runs RBI Walks Years CAtBat CHits CHmRun CRuns CRBI CWalks League Division PutOuts Assists Errors Salary NewLeague
-Andy Allanson      293   66     1   30  29    14     1    293    66      1    30   29     14      A        E     446      33     20     NA         A
-Alan Ashby         315   81     7   24  38    39    14   3449   835     69   321  414    375      N        W     632      43     10  475.0         N
-Alvin Davis        479  130    18   66  72    76     3   1624   457     63   224  266    263      A        W     880      82     14  480.0         A
-Andre Dawson       496  141    20   65  78    37    11   5628  1575    225   828  838    354      N        E     200      11      3  500.0         N
-Andres Galarraga   321   87    10   39  42    30     2    396   101     12    48   46     33      N        E     805      40      4   91.5         N
-Alfredo Griffin    594  169     4   74  51    35    11   4408  1133     19   501  336    194      A        W     282     421     25  750.0         A
```

I want to convert all the columns and the rows with non numeric values to zero, is there any simple way to do this. 
I found here an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25276155/remove-the-rows-that-have-non-numeric-characters-in-one-column-in-r?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) how to remove the rows for one column just but for more I have to do it for every column manually.

Is in r any function that does this for all columns and rows?

Comment: Are you sure you want to remove all columns AND rows with non numeric values? In your example above everything should be removed. Is that correct?

Comment: @AntoniosK yes I just realized that thank you, I will update the question where I want everything that is not a numeric to be zero

Comment: Are you sure you don't just need the non numeric columns to be removed?

Comment: I assume you treat `NA` as non numeric, right?

Comment: @AntoniosK yes that's right, I just want to have numeric values, but still to have a matrix. So making them zero is still an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(ISLR)
data("Hitters")
d = head(Hitters)

library(dplyr)

d %>% 
  mutate_if(function(x) !is.numeric(x), function(x) 0) %>%   # if column is non numeric add zeros
  mutate_all(function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), 0, x))             # if there is an NA element replace it with 0

#   AtBat Hits HmRun Runs RBI Walks Years CAtBat CHits CHmRun CRuns CRBI CWalks League Division PutOuts Assists Errors Salary NewLeague
# 1   293   66     1   30  29    14     1    293    66      1    30   29     14      0        0     446      33     20    0.0         0
# 2   315   81     7   24  38    39    14   3449   835     69   321  414    375      0        0     632      43     10  475.0         0
# 3   479  130    18   66  72    76     3   1624   457     63   224  266    263      0        0     880      82     14  480.0         0
# 4   496  141    20   65  78    37    11   5628  1575    225   828  838    354      0        0     200      11      3  500.0         0
# 5   321   87    10   39  42    30     2    396   101     12    48   46     33      0        0     805      40      4   91.5         0
# 6   594  169     4   74  51    35    11   4408  1133     19   501  336    194      0        0     282     421     25  750.0         0
```

If you want to avoid `function(x)` you can use this

```
d %>% 
  mutate_if(Negate(is.numeric), ~0) %>%  
  mutate_all(~ifelse(is.na(.), 0, .))
```

Answer (score 2):

To remove non-numeric columns, perhaps something like this?

```
df %>%
    select(which(sapply(., is.numeric)))
#                  AtBat Hits HmRun Runs RBI Walks Years CAtBat CHits CHmRun
#-Andy Allanson      293   66     1   30  29    14     1    293    66      1
#-Alan Ashby         315   81     7   24  38    39    14   3449   835     69
#-Alvin Davis        479  130    18   66  72    76     3   1624   457     63
#-Andre Dawson       496  141    20   65  78    37    11   5628  1575    225
#-Andres Galarraga   321   87    10   39  42    30     2    396   101     12
#-Alfredo Griffin    594  169     4   74  51    35    11   4408  1133     19
#                  CRuns CRBI CWalks PutOuts Assists Errors Salary
#-Andy Allanson       30   29     14     446      33     20     NA
#-Alan Ashby         321  414    375     632      43     10  475.0
#-Alvin Davis        224  266    263     880      82     14  480.0
#-Andre Dawson       828  838    354     200      11      3  500.0
#-Andres Galarraga    48   46     33     805      40      4   91.5
#-Alfredo Griffin    501  336    194     282     421     25  750.0
```

or

```
df %>%
    select(-which(sapply(., function(x) is.character(x) | is.factor(x))))
```

---

Or much neater (thanks to @AntoniosK):

```
df %>% select_if(is.numeric)
```

---

### Update

To additionally replace `NA`s with `0`, you can do

```
df %>% select_if(is.numeric) %>% replace(is.na(.), 0)
#                  AtBat Hits HmRun Runs RBI Walks Years CAtBat CHits CHmRun
#-Andy Allanson      293   66     1   30  29    14     1    293    66      1
#-Alan Ashby         315   81     7   24  38    39    14   3449   835     69
#-Alvin Davis        479  130    18   66  72    76     3   1624   457     63
#-Andre Dawson       496  141    20   65  78    37    11   5628  1575    225
#-Andres Galarraga   321   87    10   39  42    30     2    396   101     12
#-Alfredo Griffin    594  169     4   74  51    35    11   4408  1133     19
#                  CRuns CRBI CWalks PutOuts Assists Errors Salary
#-Andy Allanson       30   29     14     446      33     20    0.0
#-Alan Ashby         321  414    375     632      43     10  475.0
#-Alvin Davis        224  266    263     880      82     14  480.0
#-Andre Dawson       828  838    354     200      11      3  500.0
#-Andres Galarraga    48   46     33     805      40      4   91.5
#-Alfredo Griffin    501  336    194     282     421     25  750.0
```

Comment: thanks but I think I did a mistake because removing all the non numerics I would have all of them zero, I just edited the question

Comment: You can also use this `d %>% select_if(is.numeric)` :-)

Comment: @Ville I've edited my answer to address your comment, please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the numeric columns with `sapply/inherits`.

```
X <- Hitters
inx <- sapply(X, inherits, c("integer", "numeric"))
Y <- X[inx]
```

Then, it wouldn't make much sense to remove the rows with non-numeric entries, they were already removed, but you could do

```
inx <- apply(Y, 1, function(y) all(inherits(y, c("integer", "numeric"))))
Y[inx, ]
```