# Removing rows from dataframe that contains string in a particular column

Tags: r, dataframe

So I'm cleaning up a huge data file in R and an example is as shown:

```
ID       Score
1001       4
1002       2
1003       h
1004       v
1005       3
```

Because the class of Score column is "character", I want to use the as.numeric function to convert 4,20 and 30 to numeric values. But since the data is dirty (contains unreasonable strings like h, v), I get the message:

```
NAs introduced by coercion.
```

When i run the following:

```
as.numeric(df$Score)
```

So what i want to do now is to remove the rows in the dataframe that contains strings with letters so that i would obtain:

```
ID       Score
1001       4
1002       2
1005       3
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove the rows that have non-numeric characters in one column in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25276155/remove-the-rows-that-have-non-numeric-characters-in-one-column-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can do this :

Convert to numeric and remove `NA` values

```
subset(df, !is.na(as.numeric(Score)))

#    ID Score
#1 1001     4
#2 1002    20
#5 1005    30
```

Or with `grepl` find if there are any non-numeric characters in them and remove them

```
subset(df, !grepl('\\D', Score))
```

This can be done with `grep` as well.

```
df[grep('\\D', df$Score, invert = TRUE), ]
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1001:1005, Score = c("4", "20", "h", "v", 
"30")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: thanks, but the first solution still produces a message "In eval(e, x, parent.frame()) : NAs introduced by coercion". But the second one works without having the message generated.

Comment: @Astrox yes,  because we are trying to change the character value to numeric there hence you get the warning message. In this case, it is safe to ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `str_detect` in the `tidyverse` package, as follows:

```
df[str_detect(df$Score, "\\d"),]
```

or

```
df %>% filter(str_detect(df$Score, "\\d"))
```

Both produce the output:

```
#    ID Score
#1 1001     4
#2 1002    20
#5 1005    30
```

Hope it helps.