# Removing rows with number in a column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe below:

```
Country        Population
123491         9.9
2348           4.3
USA            10.1
Australia      9.1
```

And I want to remove the rows where the Country is invalid, for example 123491 and 2348. The **class of Country is "factor".**

```
> sapply(df, class)

Country        Population
factor          numeric
```

I want to get the following as a result:

```
Country       Population
  USA          10.1
  Australia    9.1
```

Comment: This is opposite of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60124533/removing-rows-from-dataframe-that-contains-string-in-a-particular-column/

Answer (score 2):

You could subset your data frame using `grepl`:

```
df[!grepl("^\\d+$", df$Country), ]

    Country Population
3       USA       10.1
4 Australia        9.1
```

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(Country=c("123491", "2348", "USA", "Australia"),
                 Population=c(9.9, 4.3, 10.1, 9.1))
```

Note: If you want to reject a country based on having *any* number in it, then just use `grepl` with the pattern `\d`:

```
df[!grepl("\\d", df$Country), ]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could look for numbers as part of the Country column and exclude those that contain numbers.

```
library(tidyverse)

Country <- factor(c("123491", "2348", "USA", "Australia"))
Population <- c(9.9, 4.3, 10.1, 9.1)

df <- data.frame(Country, Population)

df %>%
  filter(!(str_detect(Country, "\\d")))
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by checking whether the value can be converted to numeric, as follows:

```
suppressWarnings(df[is.na(as.numeric(as.character(df$Country))),])

#    Country Population
#3       USA       10.1
#4 Australia        9.1
```

So, if the conversion to numeric produced `NA`, that means the value is of 
a character type. I used `suppressWarnings` so you don't get a warning when converting characters to numeric values.

Hope it helps.